# Assigning multiple Children to Grid and visualizing them

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, grid

I'm setting up an Xamarin.Forms app where i am trying to add a "Module", saving it in a list and then visualizing it on Android via grid cells.

The problem is within the visualization. The problem is that i am trying to add multiple children to the same grid cell, but they are overlaying with each other.

```
public void CreateModuleGrids()
    {

        foreach (Module item in _mm.ModulesList)
        {
             gOut.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(100) });
                gOut.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) });
                gOut.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100) });

                Label lblBez = new Label();
                lblBez.Text = item.Name.ToString();
                lblBez.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                lblBez.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

                lblBez.WidthRequest = 151;
                lblBez.HeightRequest = 25;

                Label lblStatus = new Label();
                lblStatus.WidthRequest = 151;
                lblStatus.HeightRequest = 25;
                if (item.Type == "blind")
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "100 %";
                    lblStatus.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                    lblStatus.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Closed";
                    lblStatus.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                    lblStatus.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                }

                if (item.Type == "blind")
                {
                    bmp100.WidthRequest = (119);
                    bmp100.HeightRequest = (117);
                    bmp100.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
                    bmp100.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
                    bmp100.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

                    gOut.Children.Add(bmp100, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    bmpClosed.WidthRequest = (119);
                    bmpClosed.HeightRequest = (117);
                    gOut.Children.Add(bmpClosed, 0, 0);
                }

                if (item.Type == "blind")
                {
                    ImageButton btnArrowUp = new ImageButton();

                    btnArrowUp.WidthRequest = 37;
                    btnArrowUp.HeightRequest = 50;
                    btnArrowUp.Source = "ArrowUp.png";
                    btnArrowUp.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
                    btnArrowUp.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
                    btnArrowUp.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

                    btnArrowUp.Clicked += new EventHandler(this.btnArrowUp_click);

                    ImageButton btnArrowDown = new ImageButton();
                    btnArrowDown.WidthRequest = 37;
                    btnArrowDown.HeightRequest = 50;
                    btnArrowDown.Source = "ArrowDown.png";
                    btnArrowDown.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
                    btnArrowDown.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
                    btnArrowDown.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
                    btnArrowDown.Clicked += new EventHandler(this.btnArrowDown_click);

                    gOut.Children.Add(lblBez, 0, 0);
                    gOut.Children.Add(lblStatus, 0, 0);
                    gOut.Children.Add(btnArrowDown, 0, 0);
                    gOut.Children.Add(btnArrowUp, 0, 0);

                }
                else
                {
                    ImageButton btnOut = new ImageButton();
                    btnOut.Measure(37, 50);
                    btnOut.Source = "ArrowLeft.png";
                    btnOut.Clicked += new EventHandler(this.btnTipOpen_click);

                    ImageButton btnIn = new ImageButton();
                    btnIn.Measure(37, 50);
                    btnIn.Source = "ArrowRight.png";
                    btnIn.Clicked += new EventHandler(this.btnTipClose_click);

                    gOut.Children.Add(lblBez, 0, 0);
                    gOut.Children.Add(lblStatus, 0, 0);
                    gOut.Children.Add(btnIn, 0, 0);
                    gOut.Children.Add(btnOut, 0, 0);



                }

            }
```

My expectation is having a grid instance that contains a label with the name of the module on the upper part, an imagebutton on the left side, an imagebutton on the right side, an image in the center and last a label under the image that shows the status. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use a Layout container in the Grid cell to organize your content

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you tell me in detail what you mean with Layout container, because i searched for it, but couldn't find anything usefull. Thanks!

Comment: Grid, StackLayout, RelativeLayout, AbsoluteLayout, etc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts

Comment: If you are new to xamarin and want to create a complex layout do it in xaml, will save your time.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that i am trying to add multiple children to the same
>   grid cell, but they are overlaying with each other.

The items are overlaying with each other because you add them to the **same position** in `Grid`.

To place views in a Grid you'll need to add them as children to the grid, then specify which row and column they belong in.

The last two parameter in function `grid.Children.Add` specify the position of the item in Grid. For example, there is a Grid with two rows and two Columns, then (0,0) means `top left`, and (1,1) means `bottom right`.

```
// left, top
grid.Children.Add(topLeft, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(topRight, 1, 0);
grid.Children.Add(bottomLeft, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(bottomRight, 1, 1);
```

Back to your code, you add all your elements to (0,0), so they will appear in the same position.

```
gOut.Children.Add(lblBez, 0, 0);
gOut.Children.Add(lblStatus, 0, 0);
gOut.Children.Add(btnIn, 0, 0);
gOut.Children.Add(btnOut, 0, 0);
```

Another problem in your code is you need a `Layout container`(Like `stacklayout` or other [layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/)) as `Jason` said to manage your elements. Because you create them in a `foreach` loop, and  in each loop you add the same thing with same position to the `gOut`.

I think the RIGHT way is create a `Grid` with your `labels` and `imageButtons` with right position in each loop.Then add this `Grid` to a Layout container(This layout container is use to layout the Grid created in each loop). At last, set this `layout container` as ContentPage's content, `Content = layout container` to display your elements.

Have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) may help you and there is also a [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/Layout/) there.